# What to call a group of functions that contain: Save to Account, Print Information, Email Information, Copy Data to Clipboard, and Create Citation

Tags: menu, grouped-list

Just like the question says, I have several items that are part of a menu. I have a button that triggers the menu. Right now it just says "Tools", and I don't believe it is clear enough. The items in the menu are: Save to Account, Print Information, Email Information, Copy Data to Clipboard, and Create Citation.

Comment: Impossible to answer without more context. Us UXers need context - where is this shown? What else is there? Who are the users? I've seen generics like `Actions` work for this, but without context it is impossible to say.

Comment: Like @Izhaki said the context would make help a bit but with this limited information, Actions & Info, Steps, More, Information, View Account etc (Any of these can go)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking the Stack Exchange community to participate in research that should be directed at their actual users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are some very specific items, I'd start with asking IF they should even be grouped together. Then I'd probably ask if you're working on a web application, desktop application or mobile application, each slightly changes what the "norm" is for some of these behaviours.

- Save & Print could naturally be found under something like File, also could potentially be handled by icon buttons outside of the menu (you may even want to do both menu and buttons)
- Email could be in a Share menu item or just an icon button
- Copy & Create Citation, I don't think I've ever seen either of these in a menu nor looked for them in a menu. Is there some reason Copy has to be done through a menu as opposed to the expected right-clicks or shortcuts? Any way you could have a Create Citation action shown on page to make it clearer that that is an option.

If you have to group them all together for some reason Actions, Tools, Utilities, File all kinda of work. I don't see any way to label these in a way that's going to be super intuitive for users.